# Symfony 2 form won't update entity, if only image changes

Tags: php, symfony

I have entity good with file upload and I have such problem -  if I only update image, without changing any fields, image won't be updated. But if I change one more field, like price and change image, new image will be uploaded.

**editAction:**

```
public function editAction(Request $request, Good $good)
{
    $deleteForm = $this->createDeleteForm($good);
    $editForm = $this->createForm('Shop\ShopBundle\Form\GoodType', $good);
    $editForm->handleRequest($request);
    if ($editForm->isSubmitted() && $editForm->isValid()) {
        $this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->flush();
        //return $this->redirectToRoute('app_good_edit', array('id' => $good->getId()));
    }

    return $this->render('ShopShopBundle:good:edit.html.twig', array(
        'good' => $good,
        'edit_form' => $editForm->createView(),
        'delete_form' => $deleteForm->createView(),
    ));
}
```

**good entity:**

```
/**
 * @var string
 */
private $logo;
/**
 * @var File
 */
public $file;
protected function getUploadDir()
{
    //return 'uploads/images/'.$this->getId();
    return 'uploads/images/';
}

protected function getUploadRootDir()
{
    return __DIR__.'/../../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
}

public function getWebPath()
{
    return null === $this->logo ? null : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->logo;
}

public function getAbsolutePath()
{
    return null === $this->logo ? null : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->logo;
}

/**
 * @ORM\PrePersist
 */
public function preUpload()
{
    if (null !== $this->file) {
        $this->logo = uniqid().'.'.$this->file->guessExtension();
    }
}


/**
 * @ORM\PostPersist
 */
public function upload()
{
    if (null === $this->file) {
        return;
    }
    $this->file->move($this->getUploadRootDir(), $this->logo);

    unset($this->file);
}

/**
 * @ORM\PostRemove
 */
public function removeUpload()
{
    if ($this->logo) {
        if ($file = $this->getAbsolutePath()) {
            unlink($file);
        }
    }
}
```

**Good.orm.yml**

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
        prePersist: [ preUpload, setCreatedAtValue]
        preUpdate: [ preUpload, setUpdatedAtValue ]
        postPersist: [ upload ]
        postUpdate: [ upload ]
        postRemove: [ removeUpload ]
```

I think form doesn't see my image update, but I don't know why. Maybe because I don't have field file in my table un db and using it only as virtual file.
Symfony 2.8

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that doctrine doesn't execute any update and therefor none of the lifecycle events in your described case.

```
$file
```

is not a doctrine managed property, so for doctrine an object where this is set and an entity without it set are equal (considering this is the only difference) meaning no update needed.

For a solution:
You can either execute the uploaded file in your ControllerAction (check it, move it, set logo property) instead of a lifecycle event or if you have a field like "updatedAt" and set a new timestamp when setting the file property resulting in the object being marked as changed.